# How to print a user's first name and last name in a Lightning Component?

Tags: salesforce1-app, lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, lightning-experience

```
<p><h2> Owner Information</h2>
<h3>$User.FirstName </h3>
<br></br>
<h3>$User.LastName </h4>
</p>
```

Comment: Rann A kind request, please start posting the use case and details of what you want, all your questions need formatting and clarity.

Comment: The Above  code is a part of my lightning component code . I just want to display the current user's first name and last name in the Lightning Application

Comment: look at this post for answer to your question : http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/100951/salesforce-lightning-get-current-users-username

Comment: You can vote for this idea to allow global user fields in lightning components reflecting current user information. https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000E7lFQAS

Answer (score 2):

You will need to get the information from the server by calling an "AuraEnabled" method on an Apex Class.

**Your Apex Class (Controller): RunningUserCtrl**

```
public class RunningUserCtrl {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static User getCurrentUser() {
      User user = [SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName FROM User WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId() LIMIT 1];
      return user;
  }
}
```

**Your Component: RunningUserCmp**

```
<aura:component controller="RunningUserCtrl"
    <aura:attribute name="runningUser" type="User" />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <p>User lastname: <ui:outputText value="{!v.runningUser.LastName}"/></p>
    <p>User firstname: <ui:outputText value="{!v.runningUser.FirstName}"/></p>
</aura:component>
```

Look at:`<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>`

*This registers an init event handler for the component. init is a predefined event sent to every component.* After the component is initialized, the doInit action is called in the component's controller, retrieving the User record.

**Your Component's Controller:**

```
({
    doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get("c.getCurrentUser"); // method in the apex class
        action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
            component.set("v.runningUser", a.getReturnValue()); // variable in the component
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

Comment: No query is needed everything exists in the userInfo static methods. You even used that to get the data int he query....

Comment: Don't we have the ability to print First Name and Last name in  Lightning component in a single line of statement ,  like where we print in a Visualforce page.... @Ardavanmet

Comment: @Eric is right. If you want to return a few attributes you can use the UserInfo class directly. In the example I returned the whole User record.

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_userinfo.htm

Comment: @Rann not that I know. Maybe in a future release?

Comment: Hi I am trying to print the username using the above code.

Comment: I have used the above code

Comment: <aura:attribute name="vasg_dev_ed_runningUser__c" type="User" />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <p>User lastname: <ui:outputText value="{!v.runningUser.LastName}"/></p>
    <p>User firstname: <ui:outputText value="{!v.runningUser.FirstName}"/></p>
</aura>

Comment: I am getting an error

Comment: Failed to save undefined: markup://gring:cspFormv2:15,70: Invalid attribute "name": Source

Comment: Change vasg_dev_ed_runningUser__c with runningUser in the aura:attribute tag.