# How display the current user name in lightning component without Apex

Tags: lightning

Hi All how to display the Current logged in user name in lightning component without writing the apex.
as i am tried {!$SObjectType.CurrentUser.Id} this, it will display only Id not name.
Can anyone help me out

Comment: Aura or Lightning Web Component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first welcome to the salesforce stackexchange!

Here I found an answer which will help you:

[Salesforce lightning get current users username](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/100951/salesforce-lightning-get-current-users-username)

> We can make use of Lightning Data service to access any of the user fields on the Lightning component without need to use apex controller.
>
> Example:

```
<aura:attribute name="currentUser" type="User"/>
   <force:recordData aura:id="recordLoader" recordId="{!$SObjectType.CurrentUser.Id}" 
fields="FirstName, LastName" 
targetFields="{!v.currentUser}"/>
```

Access the value using the syntax: {!v.currentUser.FirstName}

Probably you can just use 'Name' in the fields property of recordData

Hope it works!

Regards,
Bernhard

Answer (score 6):

If you are using LWC then you can get current user name using below :

```
import {LightningElement,wire,track} from 'lwc';
import {getRecord} from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
 
import USER_ID from '@salesforce/user/Id';
 
import NAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/User.Name';
 
 
export default class Userinfoexample extends LightningElement {
    @track error ;
    @track name;
    @wire(getRecord, {
        recordId: USER_ID,
        fields: [NAME_FIELD]
    }) wireuser({
        error,
        data
    }) {
        if (error) {
           this.error = error ; 
        } else if (data) {
            this.name = data.fields.Name.value;
        }
    }
 
}
```

Comment: Love this answer!